# Remove Gnome Notifications or set Permanent Do not Disturb

Tags: gnome, 20.04

I am trying to remove the popup notifications completely from Gnome. The notifications I mention are this:

[image]

I do not wish to see ANY notification at all from any app. Mainly because of 2 things:

- Notification get in the way of me clicking a Browser tab
- Notification stays way too long in there when I am in a hurry

Since I can't find a way of making the notification smaller (at least in an easy manner), moving it somewhere else, or even telling the option of Do Not disturb to stay fixed (when I reboot the PC it goes back to off). I am then looking for a way to completely disable this notifications altogether.

I have tried going to settings and disabling everything in there with no luck (and also because I can't do one app at a time and the idea of an option for DISABLE ALL is not there).

[image]

Comment: Hi PRATAP, yes, whatever removes the notifications from showing in a fairly easy way will solve my problem.

Comment: Hi PRATAP, save the last one as an answer and I will accept / upvote it. Thank you friend. That removes one very annoying problem for me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since some earlier versions of GNOME, one unclear thing is why some of the `gsettings` keys are not persistent after a logout or reboot.

For this case, the workaround is to create a startup application preference to turn off this particular key like this, so that the key is turned off after a logout or reboot.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.notifications show-banners false
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this, no clue why this isn't an out-of-the-box setting in Ubuntu, many many cheers +1

Comment: ***How*** to "create a startup application preference"? For example, it seems Startup Applications in Gnome Tweak Tools just shows a list of already installed apps, with no command lines.

Comment: This was [a gnome-shell bug](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1873692) and it was fixed in Ubuntu 20.04 the very same day as you last edited your answer.