# Ubuntu turn off notifications while gaming

Tags: shutdown, games, 20.04, notification

Is there a way to automatically silent, or off all kind of notifications when I am playing a game? If ubuntu does not know whether the software I ran was a game can I somehow categorize it? And when a game category software runs it automatically turns off notifications(like in Windows 10)

Comment: There's a `gsettings` command [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1233682/421483) that may turn off some notifications that you might try adding around your game command.

Answer (score 0):

If you click the date/time, and open the calendar/notification view, there is a "Do Not Disturb" toggle at the bottom left.  This should silence notifications for you.

[image]

Comment: yeah, but how can i toggle this automatically when I am playing games? I mean when I start the game in enables do not disturb and when I stop the game it disables do not disturb?