# Disable notifications at Startup

Tags: 20.04, printing, notification

I am going ahead and asking this question a second time because it was not actually answered and the answer isn't what I was looking for.
When you boot up Ubuntu, notifications will come in **even if you disable them in settings**
I want to disable all notifications, or find a way to stop this notification. The notification in question is a printer notification.
The answer I was given in a previous post linked to a similar issue that solves it by disabling printer auto-discovery, which I don't want to do. I want to turn off the notification, not the printer software!

One way I was thinking could solve this would be to somehow prevent the cups service from starting until I log into the computer, so that notification being disabled actually is honored. Like I said, disabling the notification in settings is completely ignored at bootup.

**To clarify:** I want to have a notification preference be honored between the time I start my machine and log in for the first time, as this is when the system ignores any preferences I set.

P.S. If someone marks your question as a duplicate, can you undo that? because it was marked as answered even though it wasn't!

<strike>P.S.S. Why was this marked as a duplicate again? This is the second time this has happened. I already checked these so called "duplicates" before posting the question, so the question was not answered! Sorry if I am sounding rude, but I would prefer this to be set as answered once it is actually answered...</strike>

Comment: I don't want to disable all notifications forever, just between the time I boot up and log in. After I log in for the first time, Ubuntu follows my notification preferences that I set in the settings app. I just don't like seeing the printer added notification every time I boot up my machine.

Comment: @PRATAP Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @PRATAP It only occurs at first boot. After that, the notification doesn't appear any more until I reboot my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround from this post [Remove Gnome Notifications or set Permanent Do not Disturb](https://askubuntu.com/q/1233682/739431), you may wish to disable all the notifications for ***login*** screen. the workaround will not deal with Desktop.

I tried several ways as it depended on simple gsettings key mentioned in the above link but situation got complex.. I did several times re-installation of OS to confirm if the method is working or not.. and this is the final workout..

What worked for me is this script..

```
#!/bin/bash

keys=/etc/dconf/db/gdm.d/no-notifications
locks=/etc/dconf/db/gdm.d/locks/no-notifications
profile=/etc/dconf/profile/gdm

install -D /dev/null $keys
install -D /dev/null $locks
install -D /dev/null $profile

echo "[org/gnome/desktop/notifications]
show-banners=false" >> $keys

echo "/org/gnome/desktop/notifications/show-banners" >> $locks

echo "user-db:user
system-db:gdm" >> $profile

dconf update
```

So save the above content in a text file and run

```
sudo bash <scriptname>
```

Reboot to see the change..

[image]

To revert the changes run the below commands one by one

```
rm -r /etc/dconf/profile/gdm /etc/dconf/db/gdm.d
dconf update
```

Comment: I ran this script and can confirm that this fixes the problem! Thanks!