# Is there a way to toggle Do Not Disturb from the commandline?

Tags: command-line, gnome

Is there a command or flag we can pass to enable or disable do not disturb? Right now the only way I know of is through clicking on the date and time and then the toggle button. This would help in making a keyboard shortcut to toggle it when needed.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1233682/739431 use the command in the answer

Comment: For toggling a little modification of command required..  Can you manage that from above command or need it?

Comment: @UnKNOWn Ok Thank you! I can manage and create my own script, I'll post it later on when I get to it. I appreciate it!

Comment: This was [a bug](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1873692) which has been fixed, so there is no reason any longer for such a thing you ask for. Updating your packages should be sufficient.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks [to @UnKNOWn](https://askubuntu.com/q/1233682/739431), I found this command. To turn "Do Not Disturb" mode *on*, run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.notifications show-banners false
```

And to turn it *off*, run the same command replacing `false` with `true`.

With a little tweaking, I was able to create a script to toggle Do Not Disturb mode. [Here](https://github.com/joshpetit/toggle_dnd) is the GitHub repo to the script. I set a keyboard shortcut in the settings to make it usable.

Edit: For anyone not wanting to deal with a script, you can simply use Super + V to open up the notifications menu and press space to toggle DND. Realized this the day after, but I hope the script helps haha.

Comment: Ok nice script..

Comment: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.notifications show-banners <true|false>`

Comment: The toggle_dnd script worked very well for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a fancy one-liner to toggle it, you can use following:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.notifications show-banners $(if [ "$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.notifications show-banners)" = "true" ]; then echo "false"; else echo "true"; fi)
```

Comment: Perfect to bind a custom keyboard shortcut. Thanks.
`bash -c 'gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.notifications show-banners $(if [ "$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.notifications show-banners)" = "true" ]; then echo "false"; else echo "true"; fi)'`

Comment: Having a single keybind to do both was the exact reason I needed it. Didn't like the clumsy "one for on, one for off" approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this through Python as well. Using something like systemd/supervisord/etc, this can be done automatically:

```
import subprocess
import time

# Time to set when dnd should start/stop
dnd_time = {'start': {'hour': 17, 'minute': 00}, 'end': {'hour': 8, 'minute': 00}} 
sleep_time = 30


def get_dnd_status():
    enabled = None
    # get to check
    status = subprocess.check_output(['gsettings', 'get', 'org.gnome.desktop.notifications', 'show-banners']).strip().decode()
    # 'false' means DND is enabled
    if status == 'false':
        enabled = True
    else:
        enabled = False
    return enabled


def set_dnd_status(to):
    # set to apply
    set_it = subprocess.check_output(['gsettings', 'set', 'org.gnome.desktop.notifications', 'show-banners', f'{to}'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    current_time = time.localtime()
    if dnd_time['start']['hour'] >= current_time.tm_hour >= dnd_time['end']['hour']:
        set_dnd_status('true')
    else:
        enabled = get_dnd_status()
        if enabled:
            set_dnd_status('false')
    time.sleep(sleep_time)
```

Comment: Hey Scott, I appreciate your answer! Generally it's not that good of a practice to have a while true loop, but I definitely see how your solution does work. A better practice might be to set up a cron job for a script that checks if dnd should be activated and does so. Either way, thanks for your contribution!

Comment: Sure, that's totally understandable. I sketched it up in maybe 15 minutes and felt it was a nice starting point. A cron job is a pretty good idea too.

Comment: I've since removed the while loop. The only thing this version doesn't do is actually pay attention to minutes, even though they're in the dnd_time dictionary. But that's easy enough to add support for.

Answer (score 0):

(Your question mentions that you are looking for keyboard shortcut)
The default key combination (as of Ubuntu 22.04) "Super+V" opens the notification drawer, and then pressing space should toggle the do not disturb.