# How do I prevent the popup window telling me I have to update/upgrade software or to reboot?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, notification

I'm creating an embedded system and once in a while I get this popup telling me I have to upgrade or to reboot the computer.

Since the system is expected to run on its own, telling the user anything like that is not going to be useful at all, ever.

So I've been looking into making those popups not appear but so far no luck.

Anyone knows how to prevent these?

I've found a way to [prevents simple notifications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233682/remove-gnome-notifications-or-set-permanent-do-not-disturb), and that works, but so far no luck about the restart/upgrade popups.

Comment: This is exactly why embedded systems should be using snaps instead of debs.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better then just to disable the Automatic Updates so that you never had to worry about  the popups telling you to upgrade or restart?

Comment: @Terrance That's an idea, although I was thinking that it's not too bad to have auto-updates. At the same time, at some point it could break the code too...