# How to clear ubuntu 20.04 Gnome notifications?

Tags: notification

I do not know how to formulate this question, i would like to remove this kind of card/notification. When clicking on the button "Clear" the other disappear but not the one you can see on the image.

[image]

Look like it's blocked, look like kind of RSS, i do not reminder what i clicked from Firefox but it's there since few months.

Settings > Notifications, then disable all do not change nothing.
Then I do not see the cross to delete on hover.

How to force clear this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove Gnome Notifications or set Permanent Do not Disturb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233682/remove-gnome-notifications-or-set-permanent-do-not-disturb)

Comment: it was not exactly the issue, and already tried.

Answer (score 1):

I finally delete it with <kbd>SUPER</kbd> + <kbd>m</kbd> then it's automatically selected then i click on <kbd>DEL</kbd>.